# Show/Hide onclick - angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

This is what i'm trying to achieve.

section1 will be hidden at page load. When user clicks on `Advanced`, section1 should show & section2 should hide. On clicking `Basic`, the opposite should happen. Nothing happens when I click any of the anchor tags now. Where am i going wrong.

```
<div class="container" ng-init="advstatus=true">
  <a href="#" onclick="advstatus=true">Basic</a>
  <br/>
  <a href="#" onclick="advstatus=false">Advanced</a>

  <div class="section1" ng-hide="advstatus">
    ///...
  </div>
  <section ng-show="advstatus" class="section2">
   ///...
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: use `ng-click` not `onclick`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AngularJS you need to use `ng-click` instead of `onclick`.

Also, `ng-init` isn't supposed to be used unless you're in `ng-repeat`, which you are not (take a look at the [Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)).

You should set up the variable in your controller:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="myCtrl" class="container" >
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="advstatus=true">Basic</a>
  <br/>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="advstatus=false">Advanced</a>

  <div class="section1" ng-show="!advstatus">
    Section 1
  </div>
  <section ng-show="advstatus" class="section2">
   Section 2
  </section>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.advstatus = true;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r1p53pfv/)

Comment: where you found that ng-init doesn't work unless you're in ng-repeat?

Comment: @Ved Taken from the docs: "The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope." https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Comment: We are not talking about the best case of uses. You just said that  ng-init doesn't work unless you're in ng-repeat.

Comment: Ok. Got in.  and the issue  was because of onlick instead of ng-click.

Comment: @Ved Yep, that's the main problem. Changed the order to reflect importance.

Comment: @OmriAharon why we are using `ng-show="!advstatus"` instead of `ng-hide="advstatus"` ? I'm learning.

Comment: @NirjharLo Doesn't matter, you can use either one.

Answer (score 0):

This one is easy to understand

```
   <div class="section1" ng-show="state1">
        Section 1
    </div>
    <div class="section2" ng-show="state2">
        Section 2
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Advance" ng-click="sec1_show()" />
    <input type="button" value="Basic" ng-click="sec2_show()" />

    <script>

        function homecntrl($scope) {
            $scope.state1 = false;
            $scope.state2 = true;
            $scope.sec1_show = function () {
                $scope.state1 = true;
                $scope.state2 = false;
            };
            $scope.sec2_show = function () {
                $scope.state2 = true;
                $scope.state1 = false
            };
        };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple just do this:

```
<button ng-click="hideShow=(hideShow ? false : true)">Toggle</button>

<div ng-if="hideShow">hide and show content ...</div>
```